# library not found running as root

Tags: linux, root, redhat

I'm trying to run an executable as root to reduce its niceness under 0. When I try to run this executable as normal user the execution flows as expected, but if I run it as root (either using sudo or a root terminal) it cannot find a shared library. The library is in a directory under /home/user. Any suggestion as to why this is happening and how to solve? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- Move the library to a more common place
- Add `/home/user` in the root `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (e.g. by adding it in `/root/.bashrc`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to let the application know where to look for dynamic libraries.

So add your custom location (/home/user/path/to/lib) to this environment variable.